# Why /usr/local/bin is not recognisable in my C++ program?

Tags: python, c++

My C++ code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    system("python test.py");
    return 0;
}
```

I have a program `foo` in /usr/local/bin, and I can just type `foo` in Unix console and it starts.

The following Python script (test.py) works:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["/usr/local/bin/foo"])
```

This one doesn't (with a "command not found" error):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["foo"])
```

Why is my Python script, when executed from C++, not able to call the program directly?

**EDIT:**

I'm on Mac OSX. I suspect this has something to do with the folder `/usr/local/bin` not added by the C++ executable or something like that.

**EDIT:**

```
 which kallisto
 /usr/local/bin/kallisto

cat test.py

from subprocess import call
call(["kallisto"])

python test.py

kallisto 0.43.0

In my C++ run:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tedwong/Sources/QA/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    call(["kallisto"])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tested `test.py` by itself in the unix shell? If that has the same problem, you've just brought C++ in for no reason.

Comment: @LogicStuff I did, look at my edit.

Comment: the shell will look in several places for an executable named `foo` when you type it in, using `subprocess.call` by default will not do this. passing `shell=True` to the `call` function will allow the shell to search but this is deemed a security risk, if used in combination with user input

Comment: @JamesKent I hear what you're saying but I just tried adding `shell` but it didn't work.

Comment: `call` should, unless otherwise specified, copy the environment of the calling process, perhaps `/usr/local/bin` isn't in the path.  Could you run `import os; print(os.environ)` and check that `/usr/local/bin` is in there (somewhere)?

Comment: can you paste you `call` command here in its entirety? it should be something like: `call(["foo"], shell=True)`

Comment: @JamesKent isn't it in the question? `from subprocess import call;
call(["foo"])`

Comment: @ilent2 his original call is, but i asked him to try adding `shell=True` which while not the best solution (and your suggestion is the better route to follow) should have got it to work, i wanted to check it had been applied correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @ilent2, his answer solved my problem. I was using an IDE to run the C++ code and never realised that I had to tell the IDE my paths. When I ran the same program directly in the console, it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. :D